# Extract residuals from an XGBoost regression as a single raster

Tags: r, regression, raster, xgboost, xgbregressor

In `R`, using the `caret` and `xgboost` packages and [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/pelkoja/visual-xgboost-tuning-with-caret) tutorial, I am running an XGBoost regression (XGBR) and I want to extract the residuals of the XGBR. I hyper-tuned the model using the `caret` package and then, using the 'best' model parameters I used the `xgboost` package to perform the regression.

My dataset has the *ntl*, *pop*, *tirs*, *agbh* variables stored in `data.frame` (ntl is the dependent variable while the other three are the independent). Assuming that my XGBR model is called *m* and my `data.frame` is called *block.data*, I did:

```
library(caret)
library(terra)
library(xgboost)
library(doParallel)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(glue)
library(ModelMetrics)
library(readr)

wd = "path/"

block.data = read.csv(paste0(wd, "block.data.csv"))

block.data = subset(block.data, select = c(ntl, tirs, pop, agbh))

set.seed(1123)

samp <- sample(nrow(block.data), 0.80 * nrow(block.data))

train <- block.data[samp, ]
train_x <- as.matrix(select(train, -ntl))
train_y <- train$ntl

test <- block.data[-samp, ]
test_x <- select(test, -ntl)
test_y <- test$ntl

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl = makePSOCKcluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# default model
grid_default <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = 100,
  max_depth = 6,
  eta = 0.3,
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 1
)

train_control <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "none",
  verboseIter = FALSE, # no training log
  allowParallel = TRUE # FALSE for reproducible results 
)

xgb_base <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = train_control,
  tuneGrid = grid_default,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

# hyperparameter tuning
# setting up the maximum number of trees
nrounds <- 1000

# note to start nrounds from 200, as smaller learning rates result in errors so
# big with lower starting points that they'll mess the scales
tune_grid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 200, to = nrounds, by = 50),
  eta = c(0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3),
  max_depth = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 1
)

tune_control <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", # cross-validation
  number = 3, # with n folds 
  #index = createFolds(tr_treated$Id_clean), # fix the folds
  verboseIter = FALSE, # no training log
  allowParallel = TRUE # FALSE for reproducible results 
)

xgb_tune <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

tuneplot <- function(x, probs = .90) {
  ggplot(x) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(quantile(x$results$RMSE, probs = probs), min(x$results$RMSE))) +
    theme_bw()
}

tuneplot(xgb_tune)

xgb_tune$bestTune

# find maximum depth
tune_grid2 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 50, to = nrounds, by = 50),
  eta = xgb_tune$bestTune$eta,
  max_depth = ifelse(xgb_tune$bestTune$max_depth == 2,
                     c(xgb_tune$bestTune$max_depth:4),
                     xgb_tune$bestTune$max_depth - 1:xgb_tune$bestTune$max_depth + 1),
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = c(1, 2, 3),
  subsample = 1
)

xgb_tune2 <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid2,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

tuneplot(xgb_tune2)

xgb_tune2$bestTune

# different values for row and column sampling
tune_grid3 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 50, to = nrounds, by = 50),
  eta = xgb_tune$bestTune$eta,
  max_depth = xgb_tune2$bestTune$max_depth,
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0),
  min_child_weight = xgb_tune2$bestTune$min_child_weight,
  subsample = c(0.5, 0.75, 1.0)
)

xgb_tune3 <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid3,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

tuneplot(xgb_tune3, probs = .95)

xgb_tune3$bestTune

set.seed(57)
omp_set_num_threads(2) # caret parallel processing threads

# gamma
tune_grid4 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 50, to = nrounds, by = 50),
  eta = xgb_tune$bestTune$eta,
  max_depth = xgb_tune2$bestTune$max_depth,
  gamma = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0),
  colsample_bytree = xgb_tune3$bestTune$colsample_bytree,
  min_child_weight = xgb_tune2$bestTune$min_child_weight,
  subsample = xgb_tune3$bestTune$subsample
)

xgb_tune4 <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid4,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

tuneplot(xgb_tune4)

xgb_tune4$bestTune

# Reducing the Learning Rate
tune_grid5 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 100, to = 10000, by = 100),
  eta = c(0.01, 0.015, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1),
  max_depth = xgb_tune2$bestTune$max_depth,
  gamma = xgb_tune4$bestTune$gamma,
  colsample_bytree = xgb_tune3$bestTune$colsample_bytree,
  min_child_weight = xgb_tune2$bestTune$min_child_weight,
  subsample = xgb_tune3$bestTune$subsample
)

xgb_tune5 <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid5,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
)

tuneplot(xgb_tune5)

xgb_tune5$bestTune

# Fitting the Model
(final_grid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = xgb_tune5$bestTune$nrounds,
  eta = xgb_tune5$bestTune$eta,
  max_depth = xgb_tune5$bestTune$max_depth,
  gamma = xgb_tune5$bestTune$gamma,
  colsample_bytree = xgb_tune5$bestTune$colsample_bytree,
  min_child_weight = xgb_tune5$bestTune$min_child_weight,
  subsample = xgb_tune5$bestTune$subsample
))

(xgb_model <- caret::train(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  trControl = train_control,
  tuneGrid = final_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE
))

stopCluster(cl)

# apply model to the whole data set using xgboost
xgb_m <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(block.data), label = block.data$ntl)

m = xgb.train(data = xgb_m, 
            max.depth = xgb_tune5$bestTune$max_depth, 
            # watchlist = watchlist, 
            nrounds = xgb_tune5$bestTune$nrounds, 
            min_child_weight = xgb_tune5$bestTune$min_child_weight, 
            subsample = xgb_tune5$bestTune$subsample, 
            eta = xgb_tune5$bestTune$eta, 
            gamma = xgb_tune5$bestTune$gamma,
            colsample_bytree = xgb_tune5$bestTune$colsample_bytree, 
            objective = "reg:squarederror")

m

# export xgb residuals
xgb_resids = predict(m, xgb_m, na.rm = TRUE)

sb = c(ntl, pop_res, tirs_res, agbh_res)

xgb_resids = sb$ntl - xgb_resids
plot(xgb_resids)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: residuals]

Obviously, I am doing something very wrong. How can I export the residuals of an XGBR as a single raster?

Here is a very small sample of my dataset:

```
block.data = structure(list(x = c(11880750L, 11879250L, 11879750L, 11880250L, 
11880750L, 11881250L, 11879250L, 11879750L, 11880250L, 11880750L, 
11881250L, 11878750L, 11879250L, 11879750L, 11880250L, 11880750L, 
11881250L, 11879250L, 11879750L, 11880250L, 11880750L, 11881250L, 
11881750L, 11882250L, 11879250L, 11879750L, 11880250L, 11880750L, 
11881250L, 11881750L, 11882250L, 11882750L, 11879250L, 11879750L
), y = c(1802250L, 1801750L, 1801750L, 1801750L, 1801750L, 1801750L, 
1801250L, 1801250L, 1801250L, 1801250L, 1801250L, 1800750L, 1800750L, 
1800750L, 1800750L, 1800750L, 1800750L, 1800250L, 1800250L, 1800250L, 
1800250L, 1800250L, 1800250L, 1800250L, 1799750L, 1799750L, 1799750L, 
1799750L, 1799750L, 1799750L, 1799750L, 1799750L, 1799250L, 1799250L
), ntl = c(18.7969169616699, 25.7222957611084, 23.4188251495361, 
25.4322757720947, 16.4593601226807, 12.7868213653564, 30.9337253570557, 
29.865758895874, 30.4080600738525, 29.5479888916016, 24.3493347167969, 
35.2427635192871, 38.989933013916, 34.6536979675293, 29.4607238769531, 
30.7469024658203, 34.3946380615234, 42.8660278320312, 34.7930717468262, 
30.9516315460205, 32.20654296875, 39.999755859375, 46.6002235412598, 
38.6480979919434, 60.5214920043945, 33.1799964904785, 31.8498134613037, 
30.9209423065186, 32.2269744873047, 53.7062034606934, 45.5225944519043, 
38.3570976257324, 123.040382385254, 73.0528182983398), pop = c(19.6407718658447, 
610.009216308594, 654.812622070312, 426.475830078125, 66.3839492797852, 
10.6471328735352, 443.848846435547, 602.677429199219, 488.478454589844, 
387.470947265625, 58.2341117858887, 413.888488769531, 315.057678222656, 
354.082946777344, 602.827758789062, 463.518829345703, 296.713928222656, 
923.920593261719, 434.436645507812, 799.562927246094, 404.709564208984, 
265.043304443359, 366.697235107422, 399.851684570312, 952.2314453125, 
870.356994628906, 673.406616210938, 493.521606445312, 273.841888427734, 
371.428619384766, 383.057830810547, 320.986755371094, 991.131225585938, 
1148.87768554688), tirs = c(39.7242431640625, 44.9583969116211, 
41.4048385620117, 42.6056709289551, 40.0976028442383, 38.7490005493164, 
44.2747650146484, 43.5645370483398, 41.6180191040039, 40.3799781799316, 
38.8664817810059, 44.9089202880859, 44.414306640625, 44.560977935791, 
43.1288986206055, 40.9315185546875, 38.8918418884277, 46.3063850402832, 
45.5805702209473, 44.9196586608887, 42.2495613098145, 39.3051452636719, 
38.7914810180664, 38.6069412231445, 44.6782455444336, 46.4024772644043, 
44.4720573425293, 41.7361183166504, 42.3378067016602, 41.0018348693848, 
39.3579216003418, 41.6303863525391, 43.8207550048828, 46.0460357666016
), agbh = c(3.32185006141663, 4.98925733566284, 4.35699367523193, 
4.94798421859741, 3.14325952529907, 2.93211793899536, 4.52736520767212, 
4.99723243713379, 5.13944292068481, 3.92965626716614, 3.43465113639832, 
3.55617475509644, 3.4659411907196, 5.24469566345215, 5.36995029449463, 
4.61549234390259, 4.82002925872803, 4.20452928543091, 4.71502685546875, 
5.20452785491943, 5.05676746368408, 5.9952244758606, 6.16778612136841, 
4.69053316116333, 2.62325501441956, 4.74775457382202, 4.93133020401001, 
5.02366256713867, 5.74016952514648, 6.28353786468506, 4.67424774169922, 
4.56812858581543, 1.88153350353241, 4.31531000137329)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))
```

My raster layer:

```
r = new("RasterBrick", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "FLT4S", 
    byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, NAchanged = FALSE, 
    nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
    blockrows = 0L, blockcols = 0L, driver = "", open = FALSE), 
    data = new(".MultipleRasterData", values = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 18.7969169616699, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25.7222957611084, 
    23.4188251495361, 25.4322757720947, 16.4593601226807, 12.7868213653564, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 30.9337253570557, 29.865758895874, 30.4080600738525, 
    29.5479888916016, 24.3493347167969, NA, NA, NA, 35.2427635192871, 
    38.989933013916, 34.6536979675293, 29.4607238769531, 30.7469024658203, 
    34.3946380615234, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42.8660278320312, 34.7930717468262, 
    30.9516315460205, 32.20654296875, 39.999755859375, 46.6002235412598, 
    38.6480979919434, NA, NA, 60.5214920043945, 33.1799964904785, 
    31.8498134613037, 30.9209423065186, 32.2269744873047, 53.7062034606934, 
    45.5225944519043, 38.3570976257324, NA, 123.040382385254, 
    73.0528182983398, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    19.6407718658447, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 610.009216308594, 654.812622070312, 
    426.475830078125, 66.3839492797852, 10.6471328735352, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 443.848846435547, 602.677429199219, 488.478454589844, 
    387.470947265625, 58.2341117858887, NA, NA, NA, 413.888488769531, 
    315.057678222656, 354.082946777344, 602.827758789062, 463.518829345703, 
    296.713928222656, NA, NA, NA, NA, 923.920593261719, 434.436645507812, 
    799.562927246094, 404.709564208984, 265.043304443359, 366.697235107422, 
    399.851684570312, NA, NA, 952.2314453125, 870.356994628906, 
    673.406616210938, 493.521606445312, 273.841888427734, 371.428619384766, 
    383.057830810547, 320.986755371094, NA, 991.131225585938, 
    1148.87768554688, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    39.7242431640625, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.9583969116211, 41.4048385620117, 
    42.6056709289551, 40.0976028442383, 38.7490005493164, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 44.2747650146484, 43.5645370483398, 41.6180191040039, 
    40.3799781799316, 38.8664817810059, NA, NA, NA, 44.9089202880859, 
    44.414306640625, 44.560977935791, 43.1288986206055, 40.9315185546875, 
    38.8918418884277, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.3063850402832, 45.5805702209473, 
    44.9196586608887, 42.2495613098145, 39.3051452636719, 38.7914810180664, 
    38.6069412231445, NA, NA, 44.6782455444336, 46.4024772644043, 
    44.4720573425293, 41.7361183166504, 42.3378067016602, 41.0018348693848, 
    39.3579216003418, 41.6303863525391, NA, 43.8207550048828, 
    46.0460357666016, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    3.32185006141663, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.98925733566284, 4.35699367523193, 
    4.94798421859741, 3.14325952529907, 2.93211793899536, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4.52736520767212, 4.99723243713379, 5.13944292068481, 
    3.92965626716614, 3.43465113639832, NA, NA, NA, 3.55617475509644, 
    3.4659411907196, 5.24469566345215, 5.36995029449463, 4.61549234390259, 
    4.82002925872803, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.20452928543091, 4.71502685546875, 
    5.20452785491943, 5.05676746368408, 5.9952244758606, 6.16778612136841, 
    4.69053316116333, NA, NA, 2.62325501441956, 4.74775457382202, 
    4.93133020401001, 5.02366256713867, 5.74016952514648, 6.28353786468506, 
    4.67424774169922, 4.56812858581543, NA, 1.88153350353241, 
    4.31531000137329, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(63L, 
    4L)), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, fromdisk = FALSE, 
        nlayers = 4L, dropped = NULL, isfactor = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE), attributes = list(), haveminmax = TRUE, 
        min = c(12.7868213653564, 10.6471328735352, 38.6069412231445, 
        1.88153350353241), max = c(123.040382385254, 1148.87768554688, 
        46.4024772644043, 6.28353786468506), unit = "", names = c("ntl", 
        "pop", "tirs", "agbh")), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
        type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
        names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 11878500, xmax = 11883000, 
        ymin = 1799000, ymax = 1802500), rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", 
        geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 9L, nrows = 7L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = NA_character_), 
    srs = character(0), history = list(), z = list())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://rpubs.com/aftersox/xgboost-what) solution:

```
d <- tibble(pred = predict(f, newdata = xs)
, obs = mtcars$mpg) %>%
mutate(resid = pred - obs,
resid_sq = resid^2)
```

and then I `cbind` the *d* with the coordinates from my raster data and I create the residuals raster.